# Postgres: display array result per column

Tags: postgresql

I want to display an array result per column.

given: `user` table with columns `id (BIGINT)` and `branch_ids (BIGINT[])`

```
-- user
id   |  branch_ids
1    | {1,2,3,4,5}
```

Is it possible to distribute the branch_ids in their own column?

wanted output (note: :column name for distributed `branch_ids` doesn't matter so ignore c1,c2,...)

```
id | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | .....
1  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | .....
```

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What do you actually want to achieve ?

Comment: A query result always needs the same number of columns. A dynamic column number is not easily achieveable.

Comment: @S-Man I thought so, that's why I asked if it's possible. If not straightforward,it's not worth it. Thanks!

Comment: There are some possible workarounds: 1) Always return a large number of columns (e.g. the max length of your array if possible) and handle NULL values, very ugly. 2) Getting a JSON object: `{c1:1,c2:2, c3:3}` and then you are able to access `SELECT myjsonresult -> 'c1'` instead of `SELECT c1`

Comment: `select id, branch_ids[1] as c1, branch_ids[2] as c2, ...`